# flutter http add custom header value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following curl which works on postman

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/api/user' \
--header 'email: test@example.com' \
--form 'amount="5000"' \
--form 'payment_type_id="7"' \
--form 'agent_id="1334"' \
--form 'phone="0123456789"'
```

But when I try to make it work in [flutter http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) request it does not get `email` value in headers.

```
Future getSells() async {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/user'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
        "email": 'test@example.com',
      },
      body: {
        'amount': '5000',
        'payment_type_id': '7',
        'agent_id': '1334',
        'phone': '0123456789',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('data:  $jsonResponse'); // result below
      }
      return jsonResponse['data'];
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Err1::: ${response.statusCode}');
        print('Err2::: ${response.body}');
      }
      return [];
    }
}
```

`Error`

> I/flutter ( 6352): data:  {error: access-denied}

**Any suggestion of how to pass `email` in headers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way as its form request :

```
var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/api/user');
var request = MultipartRequest('POST', uri);


request.fields['amount'] = '5000';
request.fields['payment_type_id'] = '7';
request.fields['agent_id'] = '1334';
request.fields['phone'] = '0123456789';

request.headers.addAll( {'email' : 'test@example.com' });


try {
  var streamedResponse = await request.send();
  var response = await Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
  
  print(response.body);

  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  var keyData= data['data'];
  print(keyData);

} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does get data but I cannot get my results array from stream. returning data is like this `{"message":"success","data":{...}}` what I try to get is `response.body['data']`

Comment: doing this fixed it: `var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return jsonResponse['data'];` thanks